# When I attempt create a new data source on looker studio to a PostgreSQL server I get the error message

Tags: looker-studio

When I attempt create a new data source on looker studio  to a PostgreSQL server I get the error message "Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your request. Error ID: 579abce6" or some random error ID.

Online help. i asked a senior colleague

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.